# How do you use malloc to allocate space for a non-pointer object, such as a mutex?

Tags: c, malloc, mutex

I'm new to C and have been working on getting pointers and such down. I'm working on an exercise in school in which we're supposed to be malloc'ing all of our required memory, including mutexes. As far as I am aware, malloc always returns a pointer to some memory (unless it fails). If this is the case, how would you malloc for something like a mutex, which is fundamentally not a pointer?

In the assignment, it's stated pretty flatly that we have to do this for mutexes too, but I can't find how to do this anywhere.

Lastly, I don't want anyone to worry about "giving me the answer", as that's not really the problem I'm being assigned; rather, this is a necessary requisite to the memory monitoring we're supposed to be doing; I'm just not sure what the proper syntax is supposed to be.

Comment: `malloc()` accepts as its argument the total number of bytes to allocate. How big is a `mutex`?

Comment: I understand as much; I'm just not sure how to specify that that memory is "for" the mutex. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: You don't specify that is for anything, you just tell `malloc()` how much to allocate Search for `sizeof` C keyword.

Comment: So I would just malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) and then declare the mutex as usual? If that's the case, why does doing this without malloc seem to work just as well?

Comment: The mutex variable would be declared as a pointer to a mutex.

Comment: Without `malloc` your mutex would automatically vanish as soon as you leave the scope in which you declared it. With `malloc`, you can return the pointer to the caller, store it to a shared data structure, etc. — it remains useful until deallocated explicitly with `free`.

Comment: Ah, I see; that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Please get yourself an introductory book to C. They all teach you how to use pointers, really. Searching for "pointers in C" gives you a whole bunch of useful hints.

Comment: I understand, and thank you for the suggestion. The long story short is that we were expected to figure all of this out in about a week and I've really had to hit the ground running with this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You can have pointers to any type.

Your mutex is probably defined like that: `struct mutex_t {..}`. If so, you can have a pointer to it: `struct mutex_t *my_mutex` which you can later use to store pointer returned by malloc. See this example:

```
struct mutex_t *my_mutex;
my_mutex = malloc(sizeof(struct mutex_t));
```

The second line initiates `my_mutex` to pointer pointing to some memory of size of your mutex struct. Now, most probably the library you are using defines functions to initialize it like `void mutex_init(struct mutex_t*)`, which you can use to actually construct mutex in memory reserved by malloc.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Would upvote but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` will ALWAYS give you a pointer to memory to use for an object. But if you're used to using objects automatically allocated on the stack, you can always use a pointer and then dereference as necessary.

For example, if you're used to:

```
mutex_t bar;
lock_mutex(bar);
unlock_mutex(bar);
```

Instead, you would do

```
mutex_t *bar = malloc(sizeof(mutex_t));
lock_mutex(*bar);
unlock_mutex(*bar);
free(bar);
```

However, all the threading libraries I'm familiar with C expect pointer arguments. For example, with pthreads, you might do something like

```
pthread_mutex_t foo;
pthread_mutex_init(&foo, NULL);
pthread_mutex_lock(&foo);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&foo);
```

The `&foo` means you're actually already passing a pointer to `foo`, so if `foo` was a pointer, simply remove the reference operator.

```
pthread_mutex_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
pthread_mutex_init(foo, NULL);
pthread_mutex_lock(foo);
pthread_mutex_unlock(foo);
pthread_mutex_destroy(foo);
free(foo);
```

Comment: Casting the return of malloc is a bad thing? I've heard that a few times during my search for the answer; why is it bad practice?

Comment: Note that I also didn't include a check that the `malloc` was successful, which you should certainly do.

Comment: @Jsess For a couple of reasons.  First, is just cleanliness: you don't need to.  A `void *` will happily become any other pointer type you need.  Secondly, is that it can hide a subtle issue, like forgetting to include `stdlib.h`.  The compiler would assume the `malloc()` returns an `int` by default, and then complain when you try to assign it into a pointer.  But mainly it's just an unnecessary habit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
As far as I am aware, malloc always returns a pointer to some memory (unless it fails). If this is the case, how would you malloc for something like a mutex, which is fundamentally not a pointer?
```

pointers are pointers *to* things; a mutex, like any other object, can have a pointer to it. If you have some type `mutex_t` then there's a type `mutex_t*`. So,

```
mutex_t* pmutex = malloc(sizeof *pmutex);
```

allocates the number of bytes required for a mutex and stores a pointer to those bytes in `pmutex`. Note how this is different from

```
mutex_t mutex;
```

Here, `mutex` is a `mutex_t`, not a pointer to one. Access to fields of the mutex would be

```
pmutex->field
mutex.field
```

To refer to a whole `mutex_t`:

```
*pmutex
mutex
```

To refer to the address of the `mutex_t`:

```
pmutex
&mutex
```